# How to generate access token for an AWS Cognito user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I' using Cognito user pool for securing my API gateway . Now I would like to make requests to my API using postman but I need to pass in Authorization token as the API is secured. Is there any AWS CLI command or REST API to generate auth tokens(by passing username/password)?  I have searched documentation but couldn't find any examples. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do this using the following CLI commands:

***Register a user***

`aws cognito-idp sign-up --region {your-aws-region} --client-id {your-client-id} --username admin@example.com --password password123`

***Confirm user registration***

`aws cognito-idp admin-confirm-sign-up --region {your-aws-region} --user-pool-id {your-user-pool-id} --username admin@example.com`

***Authenticate (get tokens)***

`aws cognito-idp admin-initiate-auth --region {your-aws-region} --cli-input-json file://auth.json`

Where auth.json is:

```
{
    "UserPoolId": "{your-user-pool-id}",
    "ClientId": "{your-client-id}",
    "AuthFlow": "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": "admin@example.com",
        "PASSWORD": "password123"
    }
}
```

You should get a response like this if everything is set up correctly:

```
{
    "AuthenticationResult": {
        "ExpiresIn": 3600,
        "IdToken": "{your-idtoken}",
        "RefreshToken": "{your-refresh-token}",
        "TokenType": "Bearer",
        "AccessToken": "{your-access-token}"
    },
    "ChallengeParameters": {}
}
```

Comment: Do we need AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey if we want to get the token through REST API?

Comment: Make sure you tick "Enable sign-in API for server-based authentication (ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH)" before trying to authenticate. If you want to test your API Gateway and Cognito Authorization, then the "IdToken" attribute that is returned from the request, is the "authorization token"

Comment: The app client must be created without App client secret(uncheck this) otherwise you will keep getting below error error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the ForgotPassword operation: Unable to verify secret hash for client

Comment: @Bingo If an app client secret is set, then the above CLI commands can be run with the additional `--secret-hash` option. Instructions for how to digest the ID + secret + options into the hash value are provided [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#cognito-user-pools-computing-secret-hash)

Comment: Here's the script version with a secret hash and SMS_MFA flow: https://gist.github.com/alarv/d84e5c468e0daf9d7cb5d28e7cef9073

Answer (score 6):

Use the following command to generate the auth tokens, fill in the xxxx appropriately based on your cognito configuration,

**aws cognito-idp initiate-auth --auth-flow USER_PASSWORD_AUTH --client-id xxxx --auth-parameters USERNAME=xx@xx.com,PASSWORD=xxxx**

*Note: You can use any one username or password under applicable cognito user pool.
The client can be found under general settings--> app client*

The AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey is not required as it already defined while setting up the aws cli. If not done use the following link to set that up first
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Comment: Here's the script version with a secret hash and SMS_MFA flow: https://gist.github.com/alarv/d84e5c468e0daf9d7cb5d28e7cef9073

Answer (score 2):

There is an AWS CLI command to generate Auth Tokens. You can use [InitiateAuth CLI Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/initiate-auth.html) for this.

Note: Make sure you have done the UserPool configuration matching the expected tokens.

Comment: Do we need AccessKeyId and SecretAccessKey if we want to get the token through REST API?