# Paws::CognitoIdp::GetUser returns "Invalid Access Token"

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

##### Summary:

I tried to obtain AWS Cognito User name (OAuth2 from Google) with Perl module Paws::CognitoIdp::GetUser but I failed the code:

```
  my $GetUserResponse = $cognito_idp->GetUser(
      AccessToken => 'MyTokenModelType',
  );
```

with the error `Invalid Access Token`.

##### Environment

I am developing Web service with following environment:

- AWS + EC2 + Ubuntu 20.04 + nginx 1.20.1 + Perl 5.30.0
- Using Cognito with Google OAuth2.0

##### What I can do now

When you access my Web service, Sign In with Google button will appear. If you click it, you can run my Perl CGI script.

##### What I cannot do now

I want to obtain your Google user name and mail address, but I cannot.

##### What I did

I wrote the following code:

```
  my $cognito_idp = Paws->service('CognitoIdp',
      region       => "ap-northeast-1",
      max_attempts => 3,
      );
  my $GetUserResponse = $cognito_idp->GetUser(
      AccessToken => 'MyTokenModelType',
  );
  my $uname = $GetUserResponse->Username;
```

##### Then...

When I access my Web service, it failed with the Software error:

```
Software error:
Invalid Access Token

Trace begun at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Paws/Net/JsonResponse.pm line 22
Paws::Net::JsonResponse::process('Paws::Net::JsonResponse=HASH(0x56495fb33d78)', 'Paws::CognitoIdp::GetUser=HASH(0x56495fb41fd0)', 'Paws::Net::APIResponse=HASH(0x56495fde6f38)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Paws/Net/Caller.pm line 46
Paws::Net::Caller::caller_to_response('Paws::Net::Caller=HASH(0x56495da09a38)', 'Paws::CognitoIdp=HASH(0x56495e05da48)', 'Paws::CognitoIdp::GetUser=HASH(0x56495fb41fd0)', 'Paws::Net::APIResponse=HASH(0x56495fde6f38)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Paws/Net/RetryCallerRole.pm line 19
Paws::Net::RetryCallerRole::do_call('Paws::Net::Caller=HASH(0x56495da09a38)', 'Paws::CognitoIdp=HASH(0x56495e05da48)', 'Paws::CognitoIdp::GetUser=HASH(0x56495fb41fd0)') called at /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0/Paws/CognitoIdp.pm line 331
Paws::CognitoIdp::GetUser('Paws::CognitoIdp=HASH(0x56495e05da48)', 'AccessToken', 'MyTokenModelType') called at /DocumentRoot/index.cgi line 16
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

##### Maybe...

I referred following to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws::CognitoIdp::GetUser)

Maybe `'MyTokenModelType'` is just the placeholder and I should specify the correct code.
But I don't know how I can make it.

In addition, I want to know how can I obtain not only user name but also user email address.

##### (Additional Info 2021-11-12)

Thanks to the comment, I read the article:
[How to generate access token for an AWS Cognito user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49063292/how-to-generate-access-token-for-an-aws-cognito-user)
and I hacked AWS CLI command but I have not got the answer yet.

I think I got to do `$ aws connito-idp initiate-auth` but I cannot find what arguments I should pass.

In the AWS => Cognito => Users and groups menu, I see the entry of a user of my Web app.

Username: google_??????????
Enabled: Enabled
Account status: EXTERNAL_PROVIDER
Email: (users_email)

I changed my code like this for the experiment to find what information my Web app has.

```
  use Data::Dumper;
  my $cognito_idp = Paws->service('CognitoIdp',
      region       => "ap-northeast-1",
      max_attempts => 3,
      );
#  my $GetUserResponse = $cognito_idp->GetUser(
#      AccessToken => 'MyTokenModelType',
#  );
#  my $uname = $GetUserResponse->Username;

  print "Content-type: text/html\n\n\n";
  print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
  print '<html><pre>';
  print Dumper $cognito_idp;
  print '</pre></html>';
```

and I see the contents of $cognito_idp like this:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
  '_region_for_signature' => 'ap-northeast-1',
...
  'credentials' => bless( {
...
    'selected_provider' => bless( {
       'expiration' => 1636712506,
       'actual_creds' => {
             'Type' => 'AWS-HMAC',
             'SecretAccessKey' => '??????????????',
             'Code' => 'Success',
             'AccessKeyId' => '???????????????',
             'LastUpdated' => '2021-11-12T03:54:16Z',
             'Token' => '?????????????????????????????????????',
             'Expiration' => '2021-11-12T10:21:46Z'
        },
...
```

I hope I could get the information of the user from the data above.
My question is, how I can specify the `MyTokenModelType` value of the code:

```
  my $GetUserResponse = $cognito_idp->GetUser(
      AccessToken => 'MyTokenModelType',
  );
```

Still I want your info.
Thanks again.

Comment: *"Maybe 'MyTokenModelType' is just the placeholder and I should specify the correct code"* Yes that is correct, see [How to generate access token for an AWS Cognito user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49063292/2173773)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I hacked AWS CLI but still I have not got the answer. I put the additional info at the bottom of the question. Please refer to it if you got some time.